# duda con action result

Tags: ajax, mvc

Tengo un formulario q por necesidad se tiene q dividir en 2 puesto que la primera parte varia para unos usuarios y la segunda puede o no variar, al dividir el formulario mi primer problema fue q no podia validar todo el model por q estaba divido en 2 formularios asi que lo valide con javascript, despues de validarlo lo envio con el codigo siguiente:

```
 $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '@Url.Action("RegisterDomicilio", "Account")',
            dataType: 'HTML',
            data: $("#RegisterDatos").serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });
```

en mi controlador lo recibo sin problema

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult RegisterDomicilio(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        switch (model.selectedTipousuarioId)
        {
            case 1:
                model.Estados = GetEstados();
                return View("RegistrarUsuarioDomicilio", model);
            case 3:
                model.Estados = GetEstados();
                return View("RegistrarAlumnosDomicilio", model);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

mi problema viene cuando lo quiero direccionar desde el controlador a otro formulario, no lo hace se queda en la misma pagina original.

alguien sabe como redireccionarlo bien?

saludos

Comment: desde ajax, debes llamar '@Url.Action("RegistrarUsuarioDomicilio", "Account")',

Comment: pero eso perderia el sentido de mi action result al separarlos, lo q buscaba era hacerlo desde el mismo, no varios